# Require JS with Knockout components is looking for js file in incorrect path

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, requirejs, knockout-es5-plugin

I am trying to understand how require js works by building knockout components.I have built 2 separate knockout components for testing. My directory structure is as follows:

```
- App
  |_ Components
     |_ Like-Widget
        |_like-widget.js
        |_like-widget.html
     |_ sign-in
        |_sign-in.js
        |_sing-in.html
     |_ startup.js
- Scripts
    |_ knockout.js
    |_ knockout-es5.js
    |_ app.js
```

I have configured require.js as follows in app.js file

```
    require.config({
    paths: {
        ko: "/Scripts/knockout-3.4.0",
        kox: "/Scripts/knockout-es5",
        jquery: "/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min",
        text: "/Scripts/text"
    },
    shim: {
        "kox": {
            deps:["ko"]
        }
    },
    baseUrl: "/App/Components"
});

require(["/App/Components/startup.js"]);
```

Here is my startup.js file

```
define(['ko'], function (ko) {
ko.components.register('like-widget', { require: 'like-widget/like-widget' });
ko.components.register('sign-in', { require: 'sign-in/sign-in' });
ko.applyBindings();
```

});

my like-widget.js and sign-in.js files are almost identical for testing purpose

```
define(["kox", "text!like-widget/like-widget.html"], function (ko, template) {

function myViewModel(params) {
    var self = this;
    self.personName = 'Bob';
    self.personAge = 23;
    ko.track(this);
};

return {
    viewModel: myViewModel,
    template: template
};
```

});

```
define(["kox", "text!sign-in/sign-in.html"], function (ko, template) {

function signInViewModel(params) {
    var self = this;
    self.userName = 'User 1';
    ko.track(this);
};

return {
    viewModel: signInViewModel,
    template: template
};
```

});

this is how I am referring to require.js in my html page

```
 <script type='text/javascript' data-main="/Scripts/app.js" src="~/Scripts/require.js"></script>
```

The problem is that my like-widget component is working fine but as soon as I try to use my sign-in component, I am getting an error

> > GET http://localhost:65182/App/Components/knockout.js
>
> Uncaught Error: Script error for "knockout", needed by: kox
>   http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror

From the error it seems that requirejs is trying to load knockout from incorrect location, my knockout.js is not in components directory but in scripts directory. What I can't understand is how it is correctly loading the like-widget component?

I am new to requirejs so I am assuming I am making some naive mistake, can you please point it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the source code for knockout-es5 plugin you will see that it requires the knockout path to be set to 'knockout', not 'ko'.

```
} else if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
      define(['knockout'], function(koModule) {
        ko = koModule;
        attachToKo(koModule);
        weakMapFactory = function() { return new global.WeakMap(); };
        return koModule;
      });
}
```

If you change your require config path for knockout

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        knockout: "/Scripts/knockout-3.4.0",
        // instead of ko: "/Scripts/knockout-3.4.0" 
    }
```

it should work. You can also remove the shim for knockout-es5 (kox in your example) since it shouldn't be needed.

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly now. Never thought of digging in the plugin file :)